# Laravel select multiple fields return null

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have this query to retrieve some field values from 3 tables. the problem is if one of the selected fields is empty or null, the query returns null even when the other fields are not null and containing values. I want to retrieve the values of the selected fields even when some values of these fields are null or empty.

```
public function Profile(Request $request)
{
    # get profile Data for User
    # data from application userID
    # data retrive  to application username   address phone
    $profileData =  DB::table('users')->where('userId','=',$request['userId'])
    ->join('patients','users.userId','=','patients.UID')
    ->join('states','users.stateId','=','states.stateId')
    ->join('gender','users.genderId','=','gender.genderId')
    ->select('users.fullName','users.address','users.userPhone','states.stateName',
    'patients.hight','patients.weight','patients.bloodGroup'
    ,'gender.type')
    ->first();

    return response()->json(['data' => $profileData]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all the entries from the main table even if there is no rows in the second table you should use [left join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause):

```
$profileData =  DB::table('users')->where('userId','=',$request['userId'])
    ->leftJoin('patients','users.userId','=','patients.UID')
    ->leftJoin('states','users.stateId','=','states.stateId')
    ->leftJoin('gender','users.genderId','=','gender.genderId')
    ->select('users.fullName','users.address','users.userPhone','states.stateName',
    'patients.hight','patients.weight','patients.bloodGroup'
    ,'gender.type')
    ->first();
```